# Axler's Measure Theory $|[a,b]| = b-a$ proof?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

In Chapter 2 of Axler's Measure Theory book, found here: http://measure.axler.net/MIRA.pdf, he defines "length of an open set", "outer measure" (denoted $|\cdot |$), and proves some basic theorems about them, mainly that

1. In $\mathbb R$, if $A\subset B$, then $|A|\leq |B|$; and
2. In $\mathbb R$ for a sequence of sets $A_1, A_2, \ldots$ the following holds:
   $$\left|\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k\right|\leq\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty |A_k|$$

He then goes into a huge spiel about the Heine-Borel Theorem and more, for the sake of proving that $|[a,b]| = b-a$. Now my question is this: why couldn't he prove that using the above two theorems like so?
$$(a,b)\subset [a,b] \implies b-a=|(b,a)|\leq |[a,b]|$$
and
$$[a,b]\subset (a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon) \implies |[a,b]|\leq (b-a+2\epsilon) \to (b-a)$$
(I'm not sure where the second theorem comes in; he seems to have used it to prove $|[a,b]|\leq b-a$ though). So why did Axler need to introduce the Heine-Borel Theorem when it seems the theorems he already proved suffice? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: How do you know that $|(a,b)| = b-a$?

Comment: If you already know that $|(a,b)| = b-a$, then yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that Axler has not yet shown that the length of an open interval and the outer measure of an open interval are the same. As said in the comments, this works if you already know $|(a, b) |=b-a$, but we don't know that. All we know so far is that $l(a, b)=b-a$. This is a very different statement from the infimum definition required for the actual outer measure.

Comment: Ok in that case how do I proceed that the length of the closer interval is equal to the length of the open interval? And is there some pedagogical reason why he doesn't prove the outer measure on the open interval first (or rather, at all)?

Comment: @D.R. The closed interval has the advantage that it is compact, so a covering by infinitely many open intervals can be reduced to a covering by finitely many. Once you know that the measure of $[a,b]$ is $b-a$, you can sandwich $(a,b)$ between $[a+\epsilon, b - \epsilon]$ and $[a,b]$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon > 0$ and use monotonicity to conclude that the outer measure of $(a,b)$ is also $b-a$.